# C++ pointers reverting back

Tags: c++, recursion

There are 3 linked lists with 2 already in order. The 2 linked lists are sorted into the 3rd(`headZ`). If I pass `headZ` as a pointer like it already is it reverts back to an empty list at the exit of the function. If I pass by reference, it exits and `headZ` only contains 1 number. I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

```
void SortedRecur(Node*& headX, Node*& headY, Node* headZ){

if (headX == NULL && headY == NULL)
    return;

else if (headX == NULL && headY != NULL)
{
    if (headZ == 0)
    {
        headZ = headY;
        headY = headY->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        headZ->link = headY;
        headY = headY->link;
        headZ = headZ->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }
    SortedRecur(headX, headY, headZ);
}

else if (headX != NULL && headY == NULL)
{
    if (headZ == 0)
    {
        headZ = headX;
        headX = headX->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        headZ->link = headX;
        headX = headX->link;
        headZ = headZ->link;
        headZ->link = NULL;
    }
    SortedRecur(headX, headY, headZ);
}

if (headX != NULL && headY != NULL)
{
    if (headX->data > headY->data)
    {
        if (headZ == NULL)
        {
            headZ = headY;
            headY = headY->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            headZ->link = headY;
            headY = headY->link;
            headZ = headZ->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (headZ == NULL)
        {
            headZ = headX;
            headX = headX->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            headZ->link = headX;
            headX = headX->link;
            headZ = headZ->link;
            headZ->link = NULL;
        }
    }
    SortedRecur(headX, headY, headZ);
}
cout << "ListZ: "; ShowAll(cout, headZ);} //Test contents of headZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass headZ as a reference, then headZ pointer will not be changed when it is passed to this function. So for example if you do something like this:

```
Node* resultHead = NULL;
Node* inputA = GetInitialAList(); // (hypothetical function to get the inital value)
Node* inputB = GetInitialBList();
SortedRecur(inputA, inputB, resultHead);
```

then the value of resultHead will be unchanged, and thus it will still be NULL.
On the other hand, if you changed SortedRecur to take headZ as a reference, then the final value of headZ will point to the last element in your list, because every time you add a new element you also do `headZ = headZ->link;` - and so headZ is always pointing to the end of the list. The start of the list is lost.

I think the easiest way to solve the problem is to keep your current implementation of `SortedRecur`, but rather than passing a NULL pointer for headZ, use an initial value which points to an actual node. That way, SortedRecur can add the sorted list to the end of your headZ and it won't matter that the initial headZ pointer is unchanged. For example, here's a kludge way to do it:

```
Node dummyNode;
dummyNode.link = NULL;
Node* resultHead = &dummyNode;

Node* inputA = GetInitialAList(); // (hypothetical function to get the inital value)
Node* inputB = GetInitialBList();
SortedRecur(inputA, inputB, resultHead);
// At this point, the value of resultHead is unchanged,
// but the dummyNode now points to the sorted list.
// All we have to do now is discard the dummyNode.
resultHead = dummyNode.link;
```

Comment: Thank you!... I got it working. Ended up reorganizing my entire function. Basically, I tested for non empty headX and headY before testing if only one was empty and so on. thanks again for the help!